# Can't import Kivy in Visual Studio Code even I installed it

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, kivy

I'm using Visual Studio Code for Python and I'm pretty sure that I installed required libraries from command prompt and also from Visual Studio Code's terminal. Normally all other libraries are working except for Kivy. I don't understand why.
Here is the imports that not working when I tried to import:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
```

and here is the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

and here is the files that I installed with pip:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you provided, I have reproduced the issue you mentioned.

Then, I did the following steps:

1. I tried to use pip to install 'kivy', but it didn't work. Of course, it wasn't in the pip list.
2. I tried to install 'kivy' with conda and then the installation was successful, but it only appears in the conda list, not in the pip list.

> `conda install kivy -c conda-forge`

3. I use the above installation command again. After the installation is completed, 'kivy' appears in the conda list and pip list.
4. Under '`from kivy.app import App`', the wavy line still exists. After I reload the VSCode window, all problems disappear.

As a test, I used the following code and ran the results successfully:

> ```
> from kivy.app import App
> from kivy.lang import Builder
> from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
> from kivy.uix.button import Button
>
> class TestApp(App):
>   def build(self):
>     return Button(text = "hello")
> TestApp().run()
> ```

VSCode opens a Test file with content 'hello'.

My environment: python:3.7.7; VSCode:1.47.2 (with conda environment); Win10.

Comment: I don't know what conda is but I guess it is related to Anaconda. Whatever I install kivy also with `conda install kivy -c conda-forge` but nothing changed. Probably I must change the environment but I don't know how. Can you explain also this? And I tried also PyCharm, the error code is diffirent.
`File "C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 466, in <module> from kivy._clock import CyClockBase, ClockEvent, FreeClockEvent, \ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy._clock' `

Comment: @Nurqm This is an environment that uses Anaconda's own python interpreter in VSCode. You could refer to it to create this environment in VSCode:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments

Answer (score 0):

Check your installed packages

```
pip list
```

If you don't find kivy try to install again or go here
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Both "conda" and "pip" methods are given.

Comment: I looked to the pip list and it is already installed.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall kivy, even delete files from explorer to be sure. Then try this:

```
pip install kivy
```

Whish that your problem will be solved.